# I accidentally deleted /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades

Tags: 16.04

I deleted this file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades`. I thought it was a swap file.
What should I do? Reinstalling the unattended-upgrades apt didn't work.

```
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: unattended-upgrades is broken or not fully installed root@****:/var/log/unattended-upgrades#
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

Open a terminal,

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Run it:

```
sudo -i
nano /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20auto-upgrades
```

In the file that opens, paste these lines:

```
APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists "1";
APT::Periodic::Unattended-Upgrade "1";
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Save file

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Close nano